# Equivalence relation on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ compatible with the group structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ by letting $A \sim A' \iff A' = \pm A$. What is the easiest way to see that $\sim$ is compatible with the group structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one conceivable notion of compatibility between a group structure and an equivalence relation on a set $G$, but presumably one here means that the group multiplication $m: G \times G \to G$ and inverse $i: G \to G$ descend via the equivalence relation map $\pi: G \to \tilde{G} : G / \sim$ (to maps that define a group structure on $\tilde{G}$). But this is the same as asking that the kernel of $\pi$, that is, the equivalence class containing the identity, of $G$ is a normal subgroup.

For $G$ and $\sim$ as in the question, we have $\ker \pi = \{\pm \text{id}\}$, and it's straightforward to verify that it is normal. In fact, it is the center of $SL(2, \Bbb Z)$, and hence is normal a fortiori. (The group $SL(2, \Bbb Z) / \sim$ of equivalence classes is sometimes called the *modular group*.)

Answer (score 3):

If $A \sim A'$ and $B \sim B'$, then $A'B' = \pm AB \sim AB$